# How to implement db close in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I build a website with codeigniter and i have a class in my model like this

```
public function get_order_items($order_id) {

        $this->db
                ->select('oi.*, i.*, s.*')
                ->from('order_items oi')
                ->join('item i', 'oi.item_id = i.item_id', 'left')
                ->join('item_size s', 'oi.size_id = s.size_id', 'left')
                ->where('oi.order_id', $order_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
      }
```

How to implement to close this query with this code

```
$this->db->close();
```

where do I put the code to close the connection? before return or after return?

this method effective for making efficient connections to the database?

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 2):

There is a `db->close()` method. In a PHP environment that is not using persistent connections there is no real need to call it. For MySQL in particular, all open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution. Which in CodeIgniter happens right after the controller method finishes. So there is no needed to close the db connection. Otherwise, you can call the close connection statement: `$this->db->close();` before the return.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `pconnect` (persistent connection) within the config file to `FALSE`, then you don't have to manually close the connections since CodeIgniter will automatically close the connections, but if you want to explicitly tell CodeIgniter to close the connection, you could call the `$this->db->close();` before the return.